# Angular Google Maps Custom Marker google object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using Angular Google Maps and I would like to use a custom marker. I don't want it to be an image. I would like something like this:

```
icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 12,
          fillColor: '#2677FF',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeColor: '#ffffff',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 6
}
```

but I get an error that `google is not defined`. How do I get hold of that object?

Here is my view:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' pan='true' refresh='true'>

<ui-gmap-marker coords="map.currentPos.coords" options="map.currentPos.options" events="map.currentPos.events" idKey="map.currentPos.id" icon="map.currentPos.icon">
            </ui-gmap-marker>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

and here  is my map:

```
$scope.map = { 
      center: { latitude: $scope.position.lat, longitude: $scope.position.lng }, 
      zoom: 10, 
      options: { scrollwheel: false, disableDefaultUI: true, draggable: true, scrollwheel: false },
      events: {

      },
      markers: [],
      bounds: {},
      polylines: [],
      currentPos: {
        id: 'currentpos',
        coords: {
          latitude: $scope.position.lat,
          longitude: $scope.position.lng
        },
        options: { draggable: false, clickable: false, zIndex: 1000 },
        events: {

        },
        icon: '',

      },
      control: {
        refresh: function(){
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

google.maps.SymbolPath class sample usage;

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 10
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found how to do it:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps){
      $scope.map.currentPos.icon = {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 12,
          fillColor: '#2677FF',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeColor: '#ffffff',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 6
      }
    });
```